# How do I make a class pass through scoped allocators?

Tags: c++, memory-management, allocator

I am trying to make an allocator aware class that can be used in a vector with a custom allocator. The class has a std::string as a member and I want this string to be allocated with the allocator like the class is.

How do I make such an allocator aware class? The example below allocates the class ClassA on the arena, but it allocates the ClassA:mVarC on the default Allocator.

```
using XAlloc1 = Allocator<char>;
using xstring = basic_string< char, char_traits<char>, XAlloc1 >;

template< typename Alloc = std::allocator<xstring> >
class ClassA : public Alloc {
public:
    ClassA( xstring & str, Alloc & alloc )
        : mVarA( int() ), mVarB( double() ), mVarC( str, alloc ) {
    }

    ClassA( xstring & str )
        : mVarA( int() ), mVarB( double() ), mVarC( str ) {
    }

    int mVarA;
    double mVarB;
    xstring mVarC;
};

using XAlloc2 = scoped_allocator_adaptor< Allocator<xstring>,
                                          Allocator<char> >;
using XClassA = ClassA< XAlloc2 >;

using XAlloc3 = scoped_allocator_adaptor< Allocator<XClassA>,
                                          Allocator<xstring>,
                                          Allocator<char> >;
using xvec = vector< XClassA, XAlloc3 > ;

void foo() {
    MemoryPool<145> arena();
    XAlloc3 alloc( arena );
    xvec v( alloc );
    v.emplace_back( XClassA( xstring( "Another very long text" ) ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make a class 'allocator aware' you must

- include 'using allocator_type = Alloc;' so that allocators can query for it.
- write allocator versions of

  - plain constructor.   ClassA( const xstring & str, const Alloc & alloc )
  - copy constructor.    ClassA( const ClassA & o, const Alloc & alloc )
  - move constructor.    ClassA( ClassA && o, const Alloc & alloc )

  The constructors must have a 'const Alloc &' parameter as the trailing parameter, 
  unless you specify that the class uses leading allocator parameter.

  - plain constructor.   ClassA( allocator_arg_t, const Alloc & alloc, const xstring & str )
  - copy constructor.    ClassA( allocator_arg_t, const Alloc & alloc, const ClassA & o  )
  - move constructor.    ClassA( allocator_arg_t, const Alloc & alloc, ClassA && o )

  allocator_arg_t is not used. It is an empty struct. (I don't know why it must be there. It just must.

.

```
template< typename Alloc = std::allocator<xstring> >
class ClassA {
public:
    using allocator_type = Alloc;

    ClassA( const xstring & str, const Alloc & alloc ) 
        : mVarA( int() ), mVarB( double() ), mVarC( str, alloc ) { }
    ClassA( const xstring & str ) 
        : mVarA( int() ), mVarB( double() ), mVarC( str ) { }
    ClassA( const ClassA & o, const Alloc & alloc ) 
        : mVarA( o.mVarA ), mVarB( o.mVarB ), mVarC( o.mVarC, alloc ) { }
    ClassA( const ClassA & o ) 
        : VarA( o.mVarA ), mVarB( o.mVarB ), mVarC( o.mVarC ) { }
    ClassA( ClassA && o, const Alloc & alloc ) 
        : mVarA( move( o.mVarA ) ), mVarB( move( o.mVarB ) ), mVarC( move( o.mVarC ), alloc ) { }
    ClassA( ClassA && o ) 
        : mVarA( move( o.mVarA ) ), mVarB( move( o.mVarB ) ), mVarC( move( o.mVarC ) ) { }

    int mVarA;
    double mVarB;
    xstring mVarC;
};

// // You can specify an allocator for each of the nested containers.
//using XAlloc2 = scoped_allocator_adaptor< Allocator<xstring>,
//                                          Allocator<char> >;
//using XClassA = ClassA< XAlloc2 >;
//
//using XAlloc3 = scoped_allocator_adaptor< Allocator<XClassA>,
//                                          Allocator<xstring>,
//                                          Allocator<char> >;
//using xvec = vector< XClassA, XAlloc3 > ;

// Or you can just specify one allocator. This allocator will then be reused for all nested containers.
using XAlloc2 = scoped_allocator_adaptor< Allocator<xstring> >;
using XClassA = ClassA< XAlloc2 >;
using xvec = vector< XClassA, XAlloc2 >;

void funk() {
    MemoryPool<145> arena();
    XAlloc2 alloc( arena );
    xvec v( alloc );
    v.push_back( XClassA( xstring( "Another very long text" ) ) );
}
```